# Google Panorama (Street) view does not load second time on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have very odd bug, `GMSPanoramaView`doesn't work on second time, for most of the coordinates. (*There is one coordinate for witch `GMSPanoramaView` works every single time*)

By does not work, I mean it's just black view and all I do is this:

```
streetView.moveNearCoordinate(coordinate)
```

I've tried setting delegate, and I don't get any errors (although I get delegate call for example for `panoramaView(_ view: GMSPanoramaView, didMoveTo panorama: GMSPanorama?)`

Any ideas why `GMSPanoramaView` sometimes works and sometimes not?

Comment: I got the same issue, have u fixed?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I had to use image instead.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior appears to be purposeful given Google's obsession with efficiency.

`GMSPanoramaService`, effectively, refuses to generate the same ID more than once in the same lifecycle of the app. Google wants you to find the most efficient way (for your particular use) to generate an ID one time and retain it until you absolutely need to regenerate it (i.e. the next lifecycle of the app).

Therefore, generate an ID as you normally would and instead of just moving `GMSPanoramaView` to that ID, store that ID somewhere with the necessary persistence so that the next time that view controller is initialized, default to that stored property—otherwise, generate it (for the first time).